# Interpolate a list of points with three straight lines

Tags: python, c, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I have list of int/double 2D points. My goal is to find corresponding three lines:

[Three cases with some noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIguU.png)

Line regression is good for last case (when all of three lines are same) but what about other?
Ratio can be dummy, noises or missed pixels can be everywhere

I'm trying to split array on parts (3, 4, 5 or more pixels) and then interpolate each of them and then combine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From your image the line segments you want appear to be parallel to the X axis?

Comment: Since you are looking for an algorithm, this might be better answered on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, them can be dummy, but that three cases are usual

Comment: I can't predict how many segments will be on an image - that should be found

Comment: StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service; if you’ve made an honest attempt then edit your code into your question as a [mre] including imports and some _minimal_ data so that anyone can paste your code into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem you’re having, and explain what’s wrong with the output.

Comment: I see, do you know how to move question to stackexchange? I need an idea instead of implementation

Comment: I'm too lazy to look for duplicates, but similar questions have been asked before here. The general solution is to create a polygon from pixel to pixel (i.e. every two pixels form an edge), and then apply a polygon simplification algorithm such as Douglas-Puecker.

Comment: Right! "polygon simplification algorithm" is key-word what I'm looking for, Thanks Cris

Comment: I was going to migrate your question to https://cs.stackexchange.com but the only relevant choice the system gave me was: https://stats.stackexchange.com So, you may wish to decide which site is best for you. Then, you can delete your question here and join the other community and reask the question

Comment: Also, I'd flesh out more detail for the constraints of your problem before posting so they can give you a more accurate answer. You might need [in addition to "polygon simplification"], "curve fitting", "finding a bounding rectangle for a point set", etc. But, a full accurate description of the _problem_ will go a long way as the algorithms are _solutions_ and experts will pick those based on the problem statement.